# My hashcode will not work - is it something wrong with my equals()?;

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, hashcode

Whenever I try to run this program, I get the following output:

6150

5000

1015612567

People in list:

{Person A=100, Person B=50}

Next:

Person: Person A Hashcode: 507806258 Value: 100

Next:

Person: Person B Hashcode: 507806309 Value: 50

```
String name;
int day;

static Map<String, Integer> people = new HashMap<>();

public PeopleHash(String name, int day) {
    this.name = name;
    this.day = day;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getDay() {
    return day;
}

public boolean equals(PeopleHash other) {
    if (other instanceof PeopleHash) {
        PeopleHash d = (PeopleHash)other;
        return name == d.name && day == d.day;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 50 * day;
}

public PeopleHash peopleEntry(){
    String namn = "A";
    int schiffre = 123;
    return null;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {


    PeopleHash p1 = new PeopleHash("Isolde", 123);
    PeopleHash p2 = new PeopleHash("Jean", 100);

    people.put("Person A", 100);
    people.put("Person B", 50);



    System.out.println(p1.hashCode());
    System.out.println(p2.hashCode());



    System.out.println("People in list: \n" + people);

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : people.entrySet()) {
        String a = entry.getKey();
        int b = entry.getValue();

        System.out.println("Next:");
        System.out.println("Person: " + a + " Hashcode: " + entry.hashCode() + " Value: " + b);

    }

}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I don't get the output "1015612567".

Comment: nothing. what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The hash/equals themselves are OK. The problem is with the usage (or lack of).

The 'Person:' output shows the hash code for the [*Map.Entry*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) object (`entry.hashCode()`), and has no bearing on p1/p2. The entries in the map are added by *String Keys* and the p1/p2 objects are trivially discarded.

The Map should probably be declared as `Map<HashPerson, Integer>` such that equals/hashCode of HashPerson will be used. The individual person objects should be used directly as keys:

```
people.add(p1, 1234);
```

Then the loop can be written as so:

```
for (Entry<HashPerson, Integer> entry : people.entrySet()) {
   HashPerson person = entry.getKey();
   Integer value = entry.getValue();

   System.out.println(
     String.format("Person %s HashCode: %d Value: %d",
       person.getName(), person.hashCode(), value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with the equals method for sure. Try this -

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {

            if (other instanceof PeopleHash) {
           PeopleHash d = (PeopleHash)other;
           return name.equals(d.name) && day == d.day;
  }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested all your code , so if your are still getting some problem raise the issue I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

To compare objects the [Object.equals(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method is used. You've defined a new method with the signature PeopleHash.equals(PeopleHash).

Change the method signature to

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
```

It is always recommended to add the @Override annotation since the compiler will warn you if the method you defined does not override another method.